# Apache: mod_rewrite: generate URL based on passed PArameters

Tags: url, mod-rewrite

well i have been use  static mod_rewrite rules for some time now like i used to do this

```
RewriteRule ^Animals\.html$  wallpapers.php?f=Animals&of=0&s=Newest
```

but now what i want to do is create the URL of the leech pages with keywords... LIKE

```
preview.php?image=26
```

preview.php is my leech page & `26` is my imageID(primary key) in the database, which corresponds to a imageName, i want the mod_rewrite to create the page URL using that image name... i have been googling about but could find some usable tutorial... can any one help me learn how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it myself

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?\.html$ preview.php?image=$1
```